# Cannot get proper value in validator in flutter

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, textformfield

### Steps to Reproduce

1. [Here is the dartpad link](https://dartpad.dev/4efa1f73bfb0e87e9facc0224b2598af) go to it.
2. Enter any values to the Fields calculate the answer.
3. Add 0. to the start any Field

**Expected results:** validator should return 0.xyz

**Actual results:** validator returns 0xyz

**Work around found:** using onSaved solves this

Can anyone tell me why is it happening or is it bug in flutter then I will a new issue in the flutter repo

[image: issue]

I'm printing the value coming from validator and in onChanged parsing string value to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** 
when input `23` and then inert `0.` , this line `amount = int.parse(val);`  execute and stop and then click calculate button, so amount is `23` and `value`'s `runtimeType` is `String` `023`

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  validator: (value) {
    print("amount $amount");
    print(" ${value.runtimeType}");
    print("validator amount value $value ");
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return "Enter some amount";
    } else if (double.parse(value).toInt() <= 0) {
      return "Amount should be greater than 0";
    }
    return null;
  },
  onChanged: (val){
    print("val1 $val");
    amount = int.parse(val);
    print("amount $amount");
  }
```

You can copy paste run full code below 
The reason why `validator` not return `0.xyz` 
Because `onChanged` executed before `validator` 
So `validator` receive truncated value by `int.parse(value)`   
If you remove `amount = int.parse(value);` validator will get correct value but
this condition `if (int.parse(value) <= 0)`  will get `Invalid radix-10 number` 
You need to change to `if (double.parse(value).toInt() <= 0)`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          buttonColor: Colors.purple.shade400,
        ),
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: BillSpitApp(),
    );
  }
}

class BillSpitApp extends StatefulWidget {
  BillSpitApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BillSpitAppState createState() => _BillSpitAppState();
}

class _BillSpitAppState extends State<BillSpitApp> {
  int amount;
  int numOfPersons;
  double splitAmount;

  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Bill split app"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                splitAmount == null
                    ? "Fill the details and click on calculate to get your bill split"
                    : "Bill split is ${splitAmount.toStringAsFixed(2)}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  validator: (value) {
                    print("validator amount value $value");
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Enter some amount";
                    } else if (double.parse(value).toInt() <= 0) {
                      return "Amount should be greater than 0";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    print("onSaved amount value $value");
                    amount = int.parse(value);
                    //int.parse(value);
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Amount",
                    hintText: "1000",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  print("person value $value");
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return "Enter number of persons";
                  } else if (double.parse(value).toInt() <= 0) {
                    return "Number should be greater than 0";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  print("onsave numOfPersons $value");
                  numOfPersons = int.parse(value);
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Number of persons",
                  hintText: "5",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "Calculate",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      _formKey.currentState.save();
                      print("calculate $amount");
                      print("calculate $numOfPersons");
                      setState(() {
                        splitAmount = amount / numOfPersons;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Got your explanation but I have seen in debug that I'm getting "02" neither "2" nor "0.2"

Comment: I have edit my answer. because value's runtime type become string.

Comment: I have edited the question have a look I have found workarounds but I was confused that why I'm getting value as 02.

Answer (score 1):

It is not flutter bug however when you take amount as integer any value starts with 0, flutter takes it as 0.

```
if (value.isEmpty) {
   return "Enter some amount";
} else if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
   return "Amount should be greater than 0";
}
return null;
```

and

```
onChanged: (value) {
   amount = double.parse(value);
},
```

Comment: yes but if I'm parsing it to an int then I'm getting output as 02 not 0.2 that decimal place is not showing up

Comment: When i tried code you provided, as i parse to int i got 0 from 0.2 which is reasonable but do i missunderstand you because it doesn't make sense to get different results.

Comment: I have edited the question have a look I have found workarounds but I was confused that why I'm getting value as 02.